# Div below, not on right

Tags: html, css

I made a div called `toolbar`. Another div named `site` is supposed to be on the right. Instead it is on the left.

```css
body {
  background-color: #e3cbb7;
}

.container {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.toolbar {
  display: table-cell;
  padding-top: 35px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #444444;
  text-align: center;
}

.tools {
  display: inline-table;
}

.tools,
.text,
.clear,
.copy,
.cut,
.paste,
.replace {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 150px;
}

.site {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

p {
  margin-top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='toolbar'>
    <table class='tools'>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <button class='text'>
            Add text
          </button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <button class='clear'>
            Clear text
          </button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <button class='copy'>
            Copy to site
          </button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <button class='cut'>
            Cut to site
          </button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <button class='paste'>
            Paste to site
          </button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <button class='replace'>
            Replace to site
          </button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class='site'>
    <p>
      Put text here.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you started out with `display: table`, you can continue with that by adding a `container` as one and make the `toolbar` and `site` as `display: table-cell`.

```css
body {
   background-color: #e3cbb7;
}
.container {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.toolbar {
   display: table-cell;
   padding-top: 10px;
   width: 200px;
   background-color: #444444;
   text-align: center;
}
.tools {
   display: inline-table;
}
.tools,.text,.image,.table,.jsbutton,.addons,.done {
   margin-bottom: 6px;
   height: 50px;
   width: 150px;
}
.site {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='toolbar'>
    <table class='tools'>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <button class='text'>
            Add text
          </button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <button class='image'>
            Add image
          </button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <button class='table'>
            Add table
          </button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <button class='jsbutton'>
            Add button
          </button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <button class='addons'>
            Add-ons
          </button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <button class='done'>
            Done!
          </button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class='site'>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This one did not look the way I wanted, but it works well, and I think I'll like this way better, anyway.

Comment: I tried to put some code in the `site`, but it was lowered about 150 pixels down from the div's top. I tried `margin-top` and `padding-top`, but they didn't work.

Comment: @redwolf10105 If you update your question with that code, I will have a look and help you make it work.

Comment: There, I've updated the code in the answer to show my new code.

Comment: @redwolf10105 Add `vertical-align: top;` to your `.site` rule ... [fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/LGSon/1gpdqkgh/)

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `float: right` to the `.toolbar`

https://jsfiddle.net/t3bd3v61/

Or check this:

https://jsfiddle.net/t3bd3v61/1/

Comment: Floating is far from the best solution for creating a layout.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the browsers you need to support, you can use `flexbox` for this.  Wrap the two divs in a container element and put `display: flex` on it:

https://jsfiddle.net/h8nqa6Lo/

More about flexbox here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, by default, `div` expand to take up the entire horizontal space available to them, so it's forced underneath the other elements.

Inside the `.toolBar` css rule, add the following to have it act more like a `span` and not take up the entire horizontal space:

```
display: inline-block;
```